# Finding Enabled Row Level Security Policies and their associated names

Tags: database, postgresql

I'm looking for a way to search for a list of enabled or disabled Row-Level-Security Policies in Postgres, by table name. Whether that be through the information_schema or any other method known to you. This is in the event of forgotten naming or as a person new to the database, who needs to reference the name of the policy.

Comment: What is an inactive security policy?

Comment: Oops, i meants enabled or disabled. As in the following.

CREATE POLICY <column1_rls> ON <table> USING (user=current_user);
ALTER TABLE <table> ENABLE ROW LEVEL SECURITY;

Answer (score 0):

Okay so i've been angling my question all wrong, as i've been weighting it on "row level security" but i should have instead been emphasising "policy".
The answer to this question is that all Row Level Security information is under pg_policy or for a detailed listing of the Policy and it's Qualifying/Check conditions, then that is pg_policies.
So, the following...

SELECT * FROM pg_policy;

--or to search by table name or find policy details, then:

SELECT * FROM pg_policies WHERE tablename = 'table_name';

Comment: The missing link are the `relrowsecurity` and `relforcerowsecurity` columns in `pg_class`.